# Move file without using renameTo()

Tags: java, file, copy, cross-platform, move

In my Java program, I would like to display the progress of moving a file. I use the following snippet of code to copy files, which allows me to track the bytes copied and shows it in a progress bar. I was wondering if the code code be adapted to move files rather than just copy them?

```
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFile));
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(targetFile));


            int theByte;

            while((theByte = bis.read()) != -1)
            {
                bos.write(theByte);

            }

            bis.close();
            bos.close();
```

Comment: *"I would like to display the progress of moving a file"* - Where?  In the console, in a Window on the moon?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I do state in the question that I show it in a progress bar, but this is not the aim of my question. I only want to know if I can adapt the code snippet provided to move a file instead of copy it.

Comment: I can generate a progress bar in the console, Swing, AWT, JavaFX and probably even in HTML and if really pushed, SWT and JNI...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ok, I'm using Swing. But as I said, I think you have misunderstood my question. All I need is the code to move a file, nothing else

Comment: So what's wrong with the code you are using?

Comment: It copies the file, not moves it.

Comment: time to discover NIO http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html

Comment: @aviad I am aware of NIO but this doesn't allow me to easily track the progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so a "move" operation is a copy with a "delete" at the end, for example...

```
BufferedInputStream bis = null;
BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

try {
    bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFile));
    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(targetFile));

    int theByte;

    while((theByte = bis.read()) != -1)
    {
        bos.write(theByte);
    }

    bos.close();
    bis.close();
    // You may want to verify that the file's are the same (ie the file size for example)
    if (!sourceFile.delete()) {
        throw new IOException("Failed to remove source file " + sourceFile);
    }

} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        bis.close();
    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }
    try {
        bos.close();
    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but surely this means that to move a file, you need the size of the file free on the drive? Is this how Windows and other programs work?

Comment: One would imagine so yes.  So in order to move a file across the same disk, you need at least the enough space to make another copy of the file.  When renaming files on the same disk, this operation will be OS dependent, but generally what happens is the Disk File Table is updated directly, so the file isn't actually moved (physically) on the disk, it's index within the FT is updated to indicate the new location

Comment: Ah thanks for that. That's interesting. Is there anywhere I can read up more on this? I've done a quick search but I couldn't actually fin anything technical regarding how things work.